# How do I break out of a getline with a file?

Tags: c++

I have code where I am inputting stuff from a file. My txt file looks like this:

file.txt

> hello world
>   ...
>   1 2

The numbers at the bottom are supposed to be read into variables. As for "hello world", it should be picked up by `getline`. But I don't know how many lines there will be in the txt file so I don't know how to break out of it. Here is my code:

```
while (getline(file, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    // ...
}

file >> a >> b; // 1 2
```

If I was doing this with `cin` I could just do `Ctrl+Z` to stop `getline` loop from running. How do I break out of the `while` loop at the right time before I get to `1 2`?

Comment: There are ways, but I would actually recommend not mixing use of `getline` and `>>` on the same stream, primarily because of the confusion and hassle involved in dealing with newline characters. Consider using `stringstream`s to do internal parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each line `string line`, you can put it into an [`istringstream iss`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream). And then try to stream it into `a` and `b` using `iss >> a >> b`, if it can be done successfully, it means you enter the right line. Otherwise, you go on checking the next line.

```
int a, b;
while (getline(file, line))
{
    istringstream iss(line);

    if (iss >> a >> b)
    {
        // you are in the right line, and a,b has the values e.g. 1 2
    }
}
```

It should also work for other strings besides `"hello world"`, like `"aaa bbb cc"` etc. as long as they are not the numbers you are looking for.

P.S.: you can also take use of [`regex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/basic_regex) if you use `C++11` to check if given line has/matches the pattern you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use a condition, and a `break;` statement.

E.g.:

```
while (getline(file, line))
{
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
    // ...
    if(line == "hello world"/){
        break;//Exits the loop
    }
}
```

A `break` statement makes your code exit the most inner loop it's used in. In this case, it exits the `while` loop.

EDIT:
If you don't want to break on a specific line, then you'll better use regular expression or another mechanism (like `std::stringstream`) to find a match of the string you're looking for, and capture the part you're interested in. I suggest you take a look at [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for this.

The idea is to loop on the lines, i.e. just as you do. As soon as you have a match, you can break (the same way) and capture from the string you're currently reading (which in your code would be in the `line` variable).

Comment: I don't want to break on "hello world". I don't even know how many lines there will be before I get to `1 2`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too clear how you determine that you want to break out
of the loop.  What is the criterion?  If you want to read all
lines but the last, the simplest solution is to simply read all
of the lines into an `std::vector<std::string>`, and then
process that; you can iterate over a vector until the next to
the last element (which you can't do on a stream).  If it's some
pattern your looking to match (say `"\\d+\\s+\\d+"`), then you
can add this to the condition:

```
std::string line;
std::regex matchNumbers( "\\d+\\s+\\d+" );
while ( std::getline( file, line ) && ! regex_match( line, matchNumbers ) ) {
    //  ...
}
std::istringstream numbers( line );
numbers >> a >> b;
```

And so on.